# invariance of convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

Let $T: S_X \rightarrow S_Y$ be an onto isometry between the unit spheres of two (real) Banach spaces, and $C \subseteq S_X$ a maximal convex subset of $S_X$. Is it true that $T(C)$ is also a convex set of $S_Y$?

Comment: Linear image of a convex set is convex. $T$ maps the set to $S_Y$. So the answer is yes.

Comment: But T is not linear, is surjective and preserves distances, I think it is not possible to deduce that T is linear from that.